# Hitting limits with goroutines & aranGO

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse ~40k files into JSON and save them to ArangoDB (this is a part of my 4fun project). This can be simplified as:

```
func walkRepository(task *RepositoryProcessingTask) {
    filepath.Walk(task.Repository.Path, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        // ...
        go parseFile(task, file)
        // ...
        return nil
    })
}

func parseFile(task *RepositoryProcessingTask, file *RepositoryFile) {
    <- task.routinesChannel
    defer finishProcessingFile(task)

    // Saves to ArangoDB (opens http connection)
    err = db.Col("File").Save(file)

    // ...
}
```

So, basically, I'm spawning 40k routines. Since each routine opens file and http socket to ArangoDB (I'm using [arangGO.v2](https://github.com/diegogub/aranGO/tree/v2) ), I'm hitting 1k open file limit pretty easily.

I've tried to limit number of routines running in parallel via channel-semaphore, but with no luck:

```
const (
    maxRunningRoutines = 256
)

// on task creation
task.routinesChannel = make(chan int32, maxRunningRoutines)

// on task start
for i := int32(0) ; i < maxRunningRoutines ; i += 1 {
    task.routinesChannel <- i
}

// when parsing completes
task.routinesChannel <- processedFiles
```

Finally, I have increased open-file limit, but it causes program to crash:

```
runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7fcddd12c5f7 m=2

goroutine 0 [idle]:

...

goroutine 81348 [chan receive]:
net/http.(*Transport).getConn.func2.1(0xcc732b2120, 0xc8200ec0c0, 0x959c08)
        /usr/lib/golang/src/net/http/transport.go:698 +0x48
created by net/http.(*Transport).getConn.func2
        /usr/lib/golang/src/net/http/transport.go:702 +0x70
```

My guess is that HTTP connections spawned by DB client are not closing ASAP which causes trouble. But how could I fix it and prove it that this is real cause?

Comment: You're not showing how your semaphore is supposed to limit concurrency, and you don't appear to be using it normal manner. There's no reason for that level of concurrency when talking to the filesystem and a database, why spawn 40k goroutines for this? Your stack trace starts with a failed cgo call, but you're not showing the relevant part of the stack trace. What are you using cgo for?

Comment: @JimB 1. `parseFIle()` has `<- task.routinesChannel` in the beginning. If I understand correctly, if go routines are already drained all numbers from channel, goroutine should block. 2. I understand that I can re-write it in a manner of workers receiving file names over channel. But I'm curious if such level of concurrency can be maintained. What scares me is leaky connections (?) 3. I'm not accessing cgo directly, this is a runtime crash. Output is 38MB in size :)

Comment: I see, you're sort of using the semaphore backwards so you can use it to count files as well. You need to limit the concurrency in some manner, so spawning all the goroutines at once and having them block on the semaphore doesn't really gain you anything. You might as well try to use a reasonable number of gorouitnes, at least to eliminate other variables that could be causing issues. If you're not using cgo, it may be the host net resolver, but regardless of how big the stack trace is a random goroutine in "chan receive" is not the one that caused the fault.

Comment: There's simply not enough info here. The goroutine stack that caused the fault may help. Also, that DB package doesn't look very well tested, and the http handling doesn't look like it's going to deal with any concurrency very well. This clinet looks like it can open up an unlimited number of connections to the DB. I don't think it will leak connections, but it's going to open and close large numbers of connections when there's high concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I've reverted semaphore so it will send on attempt to lock (in `parseFile`) and receive on unlock (when parsing completes), this allowed me to restrain goroutines. Putting some of allocations after starting goroutine also helps :)